# Trying to rewrite path to StyleSheet

Tags: php, .htaccess

Basically I want my CSS files that are located in:

```
http://localhost/crm/Websites/crm/css/style.css
```

to be accessable through:

```
http://localhost/crm/css/style.css
```

I've tryed a couple of things but it's not working, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^/crm/css/style.css$ /crm/Websites/crm/css/style.css
RewriteRule ^(.+)/css/style.css$ $1/Websites/crm/css/style.css
```

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: a working rewriterule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^crm/css/style.css$ /crm/Websites/crm/css/style.css [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/css/style.css$ $1/Websites/crm/css/style.css [L]
```

Try this one and don't forget the condition this runs on:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com
```

Comment: Tryed it, still gives me 404 ... :(

Comment: Make sure that the .htaccess is located in the root, not in a subfolder like "crm"

Comment: It's located in the folder crm. I'm using xampp and i made a folder inside the htdocs folder, with the name crm. And in there, I've made the .htaccess ... It work's for other things (like rewriting everything to index.php, rewritecond -f and -f etc) so I assume it's in the correct place ...

Comment: RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [PT,L]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^crm/css/style.css$ crm/Websites/crm/css/style.css
```

Your htaccess file must be in the root directory of your website.

Comment: The .htaccess file is in the crm folder, so that is the root directory. I've tryed this and still gives me a 404 :(

Comment: The crm directory is not the root directory